# Routing a custom method with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method I'm calling named `verify`. It's job is to change a boolean from false to true on a row of my table. It accepts a parameter (the object which needs the boolean changed) but I'm getting a routing error.

My route is:

```
        get 'verify/:u_business', :action => 'verify', :as => 'verify'
```

When I run rake routes it looks exactly the way I need it but I get a `No route matches` error when I run the site.

Update:

Code in page that uses the route

```
          <table class="table table-striped" style:"width:100%;">
          <tr>
            <th style="width:20%">Name</th>
            <th style="width:40%">Address</th>
            <th style="width:30%">Telephone number</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Verify</th>
          </tr>
          <% @unverified.each do |b| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= b.name %></td>
            <td><%= b.address %></td>
            <td><%= b.reward %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Verify', verify_user_path(b) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
```

And here is the verify method:

```
  def verify(u_business)
if current_user.admin?
  u_business.verified = true;
end
```

end

More details:

I have two models. A `User` model and a `Business` model. Each user can have one business. The bit I'm working on allows admin users to verify a business by setting the `verified?` boolean to true.

When I run rake routes I get this:

`verify_user GET    /users/:id/verify/:u_business(.:format)       users#verify`

Comment: When you "run the site"? Do you have a page that attempts to use the route helper? If so, show that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Added above.

Comment: What's `verify_user_path`? Your route is named `verify`.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I run rake routes it appears as verify_user

Comment: And you're passing in a user? Best to add the related `rake routes` output and any related contextual info.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm passing in a business. More details and related rake routes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the user as well.

```
verify_user GET /users/:id/verify/:u_business(.:format) users#verify

verify_user(@user, @business)
```

Otherwise how would it know how to generate the complete link?

Comment: I shouldn't have missed that one! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @kmcgrady No problem. I'd consider using proper nested resources, though.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to set this up (excuse my pseudocoding here)

In routes.rb

```
resources :business do
  get 'verify', :on => :member
end
```

That will add a GET route like /businesses/1/verify and, without any special treatment, create a routes at verify_business_path.

Then, you can do

```
verify_business_path(business)
```

To generate the URL in your views.

In your controller:

```
def verify
  @business = Business.find params[:id]
  if current_user.admin?
    @business.verified = true
  end
  # save, render, etc
end
```

That will follow best practices, as you don't need the special :u_business parameter, just use the rails-provided :id.  And the user, in this context, is inconsequential, so a route like verify_user is unnatural here.  You just care if the logged-in user is an admin, so this route should be attached to the business model, not the user.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This seems like a much more natural way to do it.

Comment: I've tried switching over to this method but it doesn't seem to be saving the changes. I'm just calling @business.save after I set the verified variable. Is that right?

Comment: Pretty much.  if @business.save redirect_to, etc.

Comment: Hit send too quickly.  Yes, that should save, assuming you don't have any special methods in your business model.  You can also try update_attributes if you think that there's code in your model that could be conflicting (i.e. you override the verified method or something like that).  So replace business.verified = true with business.update_attributes({:verified => true}).  That failing, something more hacky would be business.update_attribute :verified, true.  This would bypass any checks you use, so, if that method works, and the others don't, then you know there's conflicting code somewhere.

Comment: Also, in a "is your refrigerator plugged in"-esque check -- is your logged-in user an admin?

Comment: The user is definitely admin. I tried changing to use the update_attributes method but it doesn't seem to work. It saves and redirects to the correct page but the business that was supposed to be updated is still not verified.

Comment: In that case, try replacing that line with the more direct business.update_attribute(:verified, true) method.  That should definitely save.  If you still have trouble, ensure that the database was updated appropriately (as in, the column verified is now set to true).  If so, then there's something in the check itself that's awry.